# Is there is a way to attach debugger to XJC Plugin? (Intellij or Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, plugins, xjc

I'm working on XJC plugin and I would like to debug it. I'm new to java and maybe I'm missing some basic stuff but I don't see how I can attach a debugger to plugin launched by xjc command line tool. Is that even possible? I .Net in VS you can attach to a process or you can event add Debugger.Launch().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main credit goes to David Tiller and his article [Make a Surgical Strike with a Custom XJC Plugin](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/make-a-surgical-strike-with-a-custom-xjc-plugin). Look at the project at the end of the article for Eclipse IDE.

IntelliJ:

1. tools.jar must be included in File -> Project Structure -> *Your Project* -> Dependencies
   [image: dependencies]
2. Debug configuration
   [image: debug configuration]

If you see XJC's output and "unrecognized parameter -XPluginName" error, check if your src folder contains META-INF\services\com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Plugin, which has the name of your plugin's class